# JBoss AS 7 Cannot instantiate class

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have the project with 2 maven modules - server and client.
I using JBoss 6.0.0 and IDEA 12.

Server:

```
import javax.ejb.*;
@Remote
public interface db {
    int hi();
}

+ 

import javax.ejb.*;
@Stateless
public class dbBean implements db {
public int hi()
{
    return 777;
}
}
```

Client:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Frame f = new Frame("Hey");
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        try
        {
        Context context;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099");
        context = new InitialContext(props);
        Object connectionFacadeRemote = context.lookup("dbBean/remote");
        db exampleService = (db) connectionFacadeRemote;
            lb.setText(Integer.toString(exampleService.hi()));

        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
          System.out.println(String.valueOf(e));
        }
        f.add(lb);
    }
}
```

Client also has the copy of the interface. 
It works fine inside IDEA ide, the application returns my 777 result :)
But if i will try to exec it from cmd:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="Main" // main class called "Main"
```

I will get an error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instatiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
```

Manifest of client is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

So why doesn't it work outside IDE?

Comment: Your classpath isn't set correctly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, then why does it work inside ide?

Comment: Because your IDE is probably providing the right classpath.

Comment: hmm, the "Copy reference" option gives to me classpath just "Main"...

Comment: Why don't you build your app with `mvn install` and then try to run that?

Comment: Because it says "no main manifest attribute, in client.jar". Of course i got nothing of `mvn exec:` using..

Comment: in the subject you have "JBoss AS7", in the question you have JBoss 6.0.0. Both can't be true.